# Same JavaScript for multiple instances of user control not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls

I am using a user control in my website which performs the functionality of auto complete textbox. I have used JavaScript for the keydown and onfocus client events. This is the code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function TriggeredKey(e) {
    var keycode;
    if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;
    if (keycode == 9) {
        document.getElementById("<%=pnlSearch.ClientID %>").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById("<%=pnlSearch.ClientID %>").style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("<%=hdfkey.ClientID %>").value = keycode;
    }
    _dopostback();
}


function pasteIntoInput(el) {
    var text = document.getElementById("<%=txtSearch.ClientID %>").value;
    if (typeof text != "undefined" && text != "") {
        el.focus();
        el.value = el.value;
        if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number" && typeof el.selectionEnd == "number") {
            var val = el.value;
            var selStart = el.selectionStart;
            el.value = val.slice(0, selStart) + val.slice(el.selectionEnd);
            el.selectionEnd = el.selectionStart = selStart + text.length;
        }
        else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
            el.focus();
        }
    }
}
```

When I use a single instance of this control in my aspx page it works fine but when I use more than one instances in my aspx page the JavaScript of all of the controls is overwritten by the last instance of the control in my page and no other control works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off i would define your javascript functins in one place, perhaps the parent page or even a globally referenced file. That way you dont have the same functions rendered over and over again when you use multiple instances of your user control on a single page.

Then instead of embedding the client IDs of your pnlSearch and txtSearch controls into the JavaScript functions I would recommend passing them into the functions whenever they are called.

The way you have it set up the JavaScript functions on the last instance of your user control that is rendered will be the ones that will be invoked every time, which will cause the functions in the previously rendered user control instances to be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the rply... My javascript is lilbit working now. but there are some issues. 1) I m passing pnlsearch id to the function but according to my code on tab press the panel should be hidden but its not working now. 2) I have used AJAX PopupControl in my usercontrol. there is also a conflict btween the popupcontrols in more than one instances. plz tell me how to solve these issues. Thanks alot for the help

Comment: Hey raina, I'd be happy to, could you please post your updated code along with an example of your usercontrol containing the AJAX PopupControl?

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I've dealt with problems like this in the past...

A block like this goes in an external js file referenced in the control ascx.

```
    function UserControl() {
    }

    UserControl.prototype = {       
        DoStuff : function() {
                var x = this.clientID; 
                window.alert(this.pnlSearchClientID);
            },
        TriggeredKey : function(e) {
                var keycode;
                if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;
                if (keycode == 9) {
                    document.getElementById(this.pnlSearchClientID).style.visibility = 'hidden';
                    document.getElementById(this.pnlSearchClientID).style.display = 'none';
                }
                _dopostback();
            },
        pasteIntoInput : function() {
            var text = document.getElementById(this.txtSearchClientID).value;
        }
    };
```

A block like this goes in the ascx file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function UserControl<%=this.ClientID%>() {
        this.pnlSearchClientID = <%=pnlSearch.ClientID%>;
        this.txtSearchClientID = <%=txtSearch.ClientID%>;
    }
    UserControl<%=this.ClientID%> = UserControl.prototype;

</script>
```

And then in the page including the user control:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var inst1 = new UserControl<%=instance.ClientID %>();  
    inst1.DoStuff();
</script>
```

The idea is that you have a base class with the functionality you need, shared across all instances of the user control. Then a derived class per instance of the user control, with a new constructor setting properties for all of the instance-specific date (ie the ids of the controls composing the user control). The base class references these properties. The derived class is named using the ClientID of the user control, making it unique on the page.

I don't have access to an asp.net ATM so there are probably errors in here...

Comment: Thanks for the rply.. but plz tell me when i have to call the parent page javascript code

Comment: You could pass a reference to whatever you need in the page javascript to the user control javascript object- set a property in the user control javascript object, pass something into the constructor, pass arguments to a method defined on the user control javascript object. If you have a similar kind of javascript object defined for the parent page, you can pass that object to the user  control when it's instantiated... Lots of options.

Comment: I tried to follow the above approach, but it did not work. Can someone help me on this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42156131/asp-net-with-javascript-using-multiple-instances-of-a-control-in-a-webform