# ASP.Net with javascript: Using multiple instances of a control in a Webform

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, user-controls

I have a User Control which i want to use Multiple times on a page. So i tried the approach of moving the Control's JS into a File and creating a Prototype for it, so that it works smoothly on the page. But when running the solution, it gives the following error:
**Uncaught TypeError: CtrlNameCtrlName1 is not a constructor**

I am not being able to find where am i making a mistake. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

User Control with markup:

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="CtrlName.ascx.vb" Inherits="MultiInstanceControl.CtrlName" %>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:Panel ID="pnlSearch" runat="server" Style="background-color: yellow;width: 30px;height: 30px;"></asp:Panel>
<br />
<input id="txtInput" type="text" />

<script  type="text/javascript" src="CtrlNameJS.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function CtrlName<%=me.ClientID%>() {
        this.pnlSearchClientID = <%=pnlSearch.ClientID%>;
              this.txtSearchClientID = <%=txtSearch.ClientID%>;
              this.txtInputControl = document.getElementById('txtInput'); 
              this.Category = <%=Category%>; 
    }

    CtrlName<%=me.ClientID%> = CtrlName.prototype;  

</script>
```

Here is the JS File Content it uses:

```js
function CtrlName() {
}

CtrlName.prototype = {
    HidePanel: function () {
        if (Category == '1') {
            pnlSearchClientID.style.backGroundColor = 'Red';
        }
        else {
            pnlSearchClientID.style.backGroundColor = 'Blue';
        }
    },
    GetSearchedText: function () {
        alert($find(txtSearchClientID).get_value());
    },
    GetInputText: function () {
        alert(txtInputControl.value);
    }
};
```

And Finally the Page which uses the Above Control with Multiple instances:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="default.aspx.vb" Inherits="MultiInstanceControl._default" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/CtrlName.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="CtrlName" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div> 1. First Instance <br /><br />
          <uc1:CtrlName ID="CtrlName1" IsMultipleFile="false" Category="1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnTest1" Text="Get Value" OnClientClick="return btnTest_ClientClick('1');" />
        <br /><br />
<br />
         <br /><br /> <br /><br />
        2. Second Instance <br /><br />
             <uc1:CtrlName ID="CtrlName2" IsMultipleFile="false" Category="2" runat="server" />
  <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button2" Text="Get Value" OnClientClick="return btnTest_ClientClick('2');" />

    </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            var inst1 = new CtrlName<%=CtrlName1.ClientID %>();
            var inst2 = new CtrlName<%=CtrlName2.ClientID%>();

            function btnTest_ClientClick(strVal) {
                if (strVal == '1') {
                    inst1.HidePanel();
                    inst1.GetSearchedText();
                    inst1.GetInputText();

                }
                else {
                    inst2.HidePanel();
                    inst2.GetSearchedText();
                    inst2.GetInputText();
                }
                return false;
            }


</script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the variable initializations after all scripts loaded like this (with JQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function()){
        var inst1 = new CtrlName<%=CtrlName1.ClientID %>();
        var inst2 = new CtrlName<%=CtrlName2.ClientID%>();

        function btnTest_ClientClick(strVal) {
            if (strVal == '1') {
                inst1.HidePanel();
                inst1.GetSearchedText();
                inst1.GetInputText();

            }
            else {
                inst2.HidePanel();
                inst2.GetSearchedText();
                inst2.GetInputText();
            }
            return false;
        }
};
```

Comment: even this throws error:
Uncaught TypeError: CtrlNameCtrlName1 is not a constructor
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (default.aspx:86)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)